# Нарисовать прозрачный круг, по контуру круга белый пунктир

Tags: html, css

Как нарисовать `div` прозрачный круг, по контуру круга белый пунктир.

- редактировать плотность пунктира
- редактировать отступы (если будут нормальными то ок)
- без javascript

Comment: ______SVG______

Comment: Что Вы сделали?

Comment: `.circle{
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius:50%;
 background: inherit (or rbga(0,0,0,0));
 border: 1px dashed #000;
}`

Comment: только есть баг - `dashed` выключается при `border-radius` в Firefox49-. Кроме того плотность пунктира не получится задать

Comment: http://alex-aka-jj.livejournal.com/66984.html

Comment: @tutankhamun не замечал, но тогда только `canvas` or `svg`

Comment: Да, выключается dashed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вкусно получилось:

```css
.circle {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border: 3px dashed black;
    background-color: trasnporent;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle::before {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    background-color: #6abde7;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Через `padding` можете задавать отступа для `border`. Цвета подобрал для наглядности, думаю разберетесь.

---

Единственное с чем могут быть проблемы, это контролирование плотности пунктира, но опять же вы можете поменять `dashed` на `dotted`, или изменить ширину пунктира.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:
<div class="circle"></div>

CSS:    
.circle {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: dashed black; 
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-width: 2px; /* плотность (ширина) пунктира. 1px - самое плотное, больше => реже пунктир */
    }
```

Comment: Не работает, Firefox 49.0.2 . Место пунктира наблюдается сплошная линия.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: *; height: *; border: dashed black; border-radius: 50%; border-width: 5px;"/>
```

Comment: Чем это отличается от второго ответа? И как решается задача изменения плотности пунктира?

Comment: Не работает, Firefox 49.0.2 . Место пунктира наблюдается сплошная линия.